# Magento 2: Themes! What are they Good for?

Tags: magento2, theme

Based on my [preliminary research](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/159013916600/what-is-a-magento-theme-the-10000-foot-view), you can use a Magento 2 theme to

1. Add additional, or replace already defined, translation strings for Magento’s `__` localization function
2. Specify the height and width for named Magento image assets
3. Replace any front end asset files added by a Magento module
4. Replace any email template file
5. Add files for Magento’s //@magento_import LessCSS directive to consume
6. Add additional layout handle XML files to merge when Magento merges a specific module’s layout handle XML
7. Override a module’s layout handle XML file (edited)

Is there anything else you change change about Magento's system behavior via a theme?

Comment: that  is good  question.. i am waiting for answer also :)

Answer (score 3):

RequireJS dependencies and paths can be defined in the [theme's `requirejs-config.js` file](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/requirejs_concept.html#config)

Comment: Nice, thank you. I did not know/remember that one.

Comment: ^ Thats somehow ironic.. I  guess to remember to see it in one of your posts  :)

Answer (score 3):

Besides overriding content, themes can also contribute template files and JS. For example you can put a template file into **{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/template.phtml** and use it in a layout xml like you would any other template, i.e. `<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::template.phtml">`.

JS files can be placed in **{theme}/web/js/script.js** and be referenced like `<div data-mage-init='{"js/script":{}}'>`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have most of it covered, some details that might be good to note:

Re: 2. In view.xml you can also alter the images in various ways. For example, you can include/ exclude extra white space in images, disregard transparancy, or replace transparency with a background color. You can also change the layout and features of the product page image gallery.

Re: 3. Maybe it’s implied, but you can also override any 3rd party modules, not only Magento core modules.

Themes also defines a parent theme to inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

Edit default widgets options for backend in frontend theme with widget.xml

here an [example](https://github.com/ubertheme/crafts-magento-2-theme/blob/master/app/design/frontend/UberTheme/craft/etc/widget.xml) i use it to add templates for magento default widgets

Comment: are you sure Magento 2  themes support this, or are you just speculating?  I don't see any widget.xml files in the core code.

Comment: here an  [example](https://github.com/ubertheme/crafts-magento-2-theme/blob/master/app/design/frontend/UberTheme/craft/etc/widget.xml) i use it to add templates for magento default widgets